# iPhone get image width and size

Tags: iphone, image, resize, get

I am new to iPhone programming.
I want to get the height and width of a image, so I can set the frame of `UIImageview` accordingly.
Any suggestions how can I get the original size (width and height) of image?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, if you have the image as `UIImage`, then you want to take a look at the `size` property:

```
CGFloat width = myImage.size.width;
CGFloat height = myImage.size.height;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try to check

> ```
> [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] size].height;
> [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] size].width;
> ```

Comment: Ok, 3 seconds faster than me, you win. :)

Comment: oh sorry. I wrote it from PC, not mac) so the only aim was to show a principle) anyway, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this also helping you:

```
UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png" ];
imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try This:**

```
image.size.height;

image.size.width;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] size].height;
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] size].width;
```

Comment: here myImage is the image name